# Using Subscript and Superscript in Processing 2?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of:

Water = **H**^2**O**

Is this possible in [Processing 2.2](https://www.processing.org/)?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you trying to display text with a subscript? Could you draw a picture or describe in more detail what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to write a chemical formula in text, for which I need subscript. There's a way to do it by downloading a GM Library according to a few message boards.

Comment: Do you want to *display* that text in the Processing draw window? Print it to a file?

Comment: Display it in a draw window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options. If you only want a few simple super/subscripts, you might as well just use unicode:

```
String s = "H\u2082O";
text(s,10,20);
```

Where `\u2082` is unicode for the `₂` character. If you want more advanced control, you could use this code [from the processing forum](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/6367/primitive-superscript-subscript-text-rendering-/p1), which can super/subscript whatever you want, rather than hardcoding the characters. The code is too big to copy here, but you should be able to include the SuperSubText class in your sketch and then use formatting strings like `H<sub>2</sub>O` in your code.

Comment: Unicode - Why didn't I think of that? I feel stupid for not even looking up putting Unicode into Processing. I'll use "I'm not really familiar with Processing" as my excuse. Thanks.